# $Array.IndexOf wrong for index 0 with prefixed comma

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I was trying to add the contents of a variable into an array. Not knowing whether the array had been initialized yet, I used the trick of preceding the data to insert with a comma to force it to evaluate as an array.
It seems that when doing this, using a preceding comma to your actual item, the `indexof` method doesn't give the proper index for the first item in the array.

In the below code sample, `$a` exhibits the issue, while `$b` works just fine; the only difference is the preceding comma when initializing `$a`.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

```
PS C:\code> $a = (,4,5,6)
PS C:\code> $b = (4,5,6)
PS C:\code> $a
4
5
6
PS C:\code> $a.indexof(4)
-1
PS C:\code> $a.indexof(5)
1
PS C:\code> $a.indexof(6)
2
PS C:\code> $b
4
5
6
PS C:\code> $b.indexof(4)
0
PS C:\code> $b.indexof(5)
1
PS C:\code> $b.indexof(6)
2
```

Since having the issue, I instead just prefixed my variable with `[array]` and got rid of the prefixed comma, and all seems well. I'm just curious what's going on.

Comment: I can confirm this in PowerShell v5 on Windows 10 (build 10240 at the moment). Very interesting, very strange.

Comment: Same behavior in PowerShell v4 on Windows 7.

Comment: The first element is a integer array. the next are just integers. I dont see a bug here. The is not element 4 since it is a sub array. `$a[0].indexof(4)`.

Comment: I see this as working as intended. ... I _think_ at least. That is what the unary operator is for. PowerShell appears to be honoring the syntax

Comment: @Matt Yeah, just figured it out myself. PowerShell interprets the first comma as the unary array construction operator, thus making `,4` a nested array with one element. Since the nested array isn't unrolled, `IndexOf` can't find the element and returns `-1` (not found).

Comment: I am doing a write up on this now unless you want it.

Comment: @Matt I thought the same thing but when i tried to evaluate it as such, it seemed like that wasn't the case. But it seems you're correct. Best way to eval (imo): `gm -i $a[0]` vs `gm -i $b[0]`

Comment: @Matt No, you got dibs.

Comment: @briantist I prefer this: `$a | % { $_.GetType().FullName }`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers ah very nice :)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I am so fully of happy that I think I might have caught onto something before you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of things here that are happening that are contributing to the misleading results. Just know that this behavior is expected,

In your first array `$a` you created 3 elements. First of which had the [unary operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx). What you actually have done is created a three element array where the first element is itself an integer array of one element. PowerShell was doing you a favour and *unrolling* the array which is why the output of `$a` and `$b` appears the same in the console.

```
PS M:\Scripts> $a = (,4,5,6)

PS M:\Scripts> $a[0].GetType().Fullname
System.Object[]

PS M:\Scripts> $a[1].GetType().Fullname
System.Int32
```

So then the reason that the [`.IndexOf()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx) did not find the element 4 is because it does not delve into nested arrays.

> Searches for the specified object and returns the index of its first occurrence in a **one-dimensional array**.

It would seem that by definition it does not search nested arrays.

If you needed to account for this then you could use the `-is` operator or just check the type.

```
PS M:\Scripts> $a | %{$_ -is [array]}
True
False
False

PS M:\Scripts> $a | %{$_.GetType().Fullname}
System.Object[]
System.Int32
System.Int32
```

Point is that I don't see a bug here. Just PowerShell being very accommodating to the point of being a little misleading.

Comment: I had a thought that there was something going on with that leading comma that made it treat the "4" differently. Thanks for the excellent explanation!

Comment: I like fun questions like this. you are Welcome.

Comment: I wish PowerShell had the equivalent of Ruby's `.inspect` method.